# Solve this proof using tautologies (no truth tables)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am having trouble solving this problem using tautologies (no truth tables).

Hypotheses: $t \rightarrow s,\;\; d \rightarrow (u \vee t)$

Conclusion: $d \rightarrow ( u \vee s)$

Comment: You have received a lot of good answer... now is up to you to choose :) And please : now that we have do your homework for you, can you let us know what rules are you allowed to use ?

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is one way of using natural deduction to prove the conclusion, given the posted premises.  It requires the use valid *rules of inference* to proceed, one step at a time.

This is not a proof using "tautologies"/logical identities, because the conclusion is not logically equivalent to the conjunction of the premises. The conclusion logically follows from the premises, however, which we demonstrate with the use of valid *rules of inference*.

Proof sketch:

$(1)\quad t\rightarrow s$ (Premise)

$(2)\quad d\rightarrow (u \lor t)$ (Premise)

$(3)\quad\quad$ Assume $d$.

$(4)\quad\quad\quad u \lor t$ (From $(2), (3),$ using modus ponents.)

$(5) \quad\quad\quad\quad$ Assume $u$.

$(6) \quad \quad\quad\quad\quad$ $u$ (From (5), reiteration)

$(7) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad u \lor s$ (Or Introduction

$(8) \quad \quad\quad\quad$ Assume $t$.

$(9) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad s$. (From (1), (8), modus ponens)

$(10) \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad u\lor s$. (Or-introduction.)

$(11) \quad\quad u \lor s$. (Or-Elimination: 4, 5-7, 8-10)

$(12) \quad d\rightarrow (u\lor s)$ (Implication introduction 3-11)

Comment: Could this proof be made by contradiction?

Comment: My answer would be a/the classical approach, via natural deduction.

Comment: I've tried a contradiction approach though.

Comment: @AaronMaroja - you can, but it is unnecessarily longer wit *Natural Deduction*... "On top" of the above proof you assume $\lnot [d→(u∨s)]$ and then the above derivation gives you the needed contradiction. It looks worthless.

Comment: "This is not a proof using "tautologies"/logical identities, because the conclusion is not logically equivalent to the conjunction of the premises."  Tautologies aren't logical identities.  Identities have an identity symbol in them.  A proof using tautologies would consist of an axiomatic proof, since the axioms and the derived theorems are tautologies.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove it in a different way with the rules of Patrick Hurley, [A Concise Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008F1AMUY) (11th edition - 2012) see **Ch.7** :

- [Rules of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference)
- [Rules of replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_replacement)
- [Conditional Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) and [Indirect Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)

---

1)  $t \rightarrow s$ --- premise

2) $d \rightarrow (u∨t)$ --- premise

3) $d$ --- assumed [a]

4) $\lnot u \land \lnot s$ --- assumed [b], for *Indirect Proof*

5) $u∨t$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

6) $\lnot u$ --- from 4) by [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplification)

7) $\lnot s$ --- from 4) by [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplification)

8) $t$ --- from 6) and 5) by [Disjunctive syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism)

9) $s$ --- from 8) and 1) by *modus ponens*

10) $s \land \lnot s$ --- from 7) and 9) by [Conjunction introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)

11) $\lnot (\lnot u \land \lnot s)$ --- from the contradiction 10) by *Indirect Proof*, discharging the assumption [b]

12) $u \lor s$ --- from 12) by [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> 13) $d \rightarrow (u \lor s)$ --- from 3) and 12) by *Conditional Proof*.

---

*We can shorten it ...*

1)  $t \rightarrow s$ --- premise

2) $d \rightarrow (u∨t)$ --- premise

3) $\lnot d \lor (u∨t)$ --- from 2) by [Material implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

4) $(\lnot d \lor u) \lor t$ --- from 3) by [Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)

5) $\lnot(\lnot d \lor u) \rightarrow t$ --- from 4) by *Material Implication*

6) $\lnot(\lnot d \lor u) \rightarrow s$ --- from 1) and 5) by [Hypothetical syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism)

7) $(\lnot d \lor u) \lor s$ --- from 5) by *Material implication*

8) $\lnot d \lor (u \lor s)$ --- from 7) by *Associativity*

> 9) $d \rightarrow (u \lor s)$ --- from 8) by *Material implication*.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - THe "shorter version" can be so, because it use all equivalences except 6) that can be derived from : $\vDash (P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow ((Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R))$ with 5) and 1) by *modus ponens* twice ...

Comment: You're right that it can be, but it probably would work as better than to state the rules of inference you've used, such as {E$\alpha$$\beta$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$ and {E$\alpha$$\beta$, $\beta$} $\vdash$ $\alpha$.  Maybe it's easier to use {C$\alpha$$\beta$, C$\beta$$\gamma$} $\vdash$ C$\alpha$$\gamma$ than modus ponens twice.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $t \Rightarrow s, d \Rightarrow u \vee t $ are true.

(1)  Well $d \Rightarrow u \vee s$ is only false when $d$ is true and $u \vee s$ is false.

(2) To say that $u \vee s$ is false is the same as $u$ and $s$ being false.

(3) As $d \Rightarrow u\vee t$ is true by hypothesis and $u$ is false (2) then $t$ must be true, which gives a contradiction since we are assuming that $t \Rightarrow s$ is true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My proof is worthless? I thought it was way shorter. Only 3 steps. Could you tell me what's off?

Comment: The proof is absolutely right; the only issue is that you are reasoning with truth values; thus it is the same as a truth table and the OP asked : "(no truth tables)" ...

Comment: As you can see from my answer above, without "semantical" argumentals, also with a "larger" set of rules (compared to *Natural Deduction*) a proof by contradiction is still longer in this case.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand, I lack these logical structure, unfortunately.  Though I think it's a very beautiful field in Mathematics and I'll keep studying.

Comment: In addition, @amWhy's proof is [intuitionsitically valid](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/); not so for my proof and your argument using truth table: both are valid only for [Classical logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/).

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion $d \implies (u \lor s)$ can be written as $\neg d \lor (u \lor s)$.

Assuming the conclusion to be *false* leads to $d \land \neg u \land \neg s$ to be *true*.

This can only be the case if $d$ is *true* and $u$ as well as $s$ are *false*.

Hypothesis $t \implies s$ with $s$ *false* implies $t$ false.

Hypothesis $d \implies (u \lor t)$ with $d$ *true* and $(u \lor t)$ *false* is a **contradiction**.

Comment: You're using rewrite rules and identities, not tautologies.